# Symmetry argument in uniform integral

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

[image]

I don't understand this "we used symmetry" argument. I get that the two distributions are the same, so there is a symmetry, but I don't get how that information is applied in taking this integral.

Is it possible to show how this works, breaking it into individually justified steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain as to what way forward you're seeking, so I'll present an approach and hope this helps.

Changing the order of integration we find

$$\int_0^1\int_0^y (y-x)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\int_0^x (x-y)\,dy\,dx$$

And now relabeling the dummy variables $x\to y$ amd $y\to x$ yields the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to break up the "changing the order of integration step", specifically noting where symmetry is invoked?

Comment: Symmetry was not exploited upon changing the order of integration.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see it is that the region of integration, $\{(x,y): x,y\in [0,1]\}$ is symmetric w.r.t. the line $y=x$ and the value of $|x-y|$ is also symmetric w.r.t. this line.  Hence the integral of $|x-y|$ where $x<y$ must be the same as the integral of $|x-y|$ where $x>y$.